# AWS Lambda to process Email attachment data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zapier

So my objective is to feed hundreds/thousands of emails into an Amazon S3 bucket and what I would like to do is to be able to extract certain metadata from these emails(which contain attachments). I would like to extract data such as the Sender's email, the Date of email arrival, the Email content and the attachment file name ad extension.

I should note that I am using Zapier to trigger whenever a new email with an attachment comes in, to send that emails attachment data into an Amazon S3 bucket. Though i'm wondering if there's a more efficient way of processing email data using AWS Lambda in this case?

(In a nutshell, what im asking is, using the following 3 tools: Zapier/AWS Lambda/S3, how can I best extract email attachment data? Could you please describe the flow?)

Comment: You can configure Lambda S3 upload event triggers that send metadata about an object uploaded to a specific bucket. Beyond that I don't know what else you can glean from the files in S3 as I'm not familiar with Zapier and how it formats things.

Comment: @AndrewA. When you mean to say "Lambda S3 upload event triggers", are you referring to the Zapier AWS Lambda upload event trigger, or something else?

Comment: Lambda can only be triggered by other AWS services: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/#Using_AWS_Lambda_to_process_AWS_events . Specifically, when you upload an object (email file in your case) to S3 you can have a listener notify your lambda function that a new file is ready to be processed: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html .

Comment: @AndrewA. What would be a "listener" in this case?

Comment: Listener is just another word for your lambda function :) It's "listening" for events from S3. You can set it up in the console with the "+ Trigger" button

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/02/trigger-actions-on-your-inbound-email-with-aws-lambda-for-amazon-workmail/?nc1=h_ls
Looking to the new "Amazon WorkMail" you can trigger lambda functions directly with incoming mails. Maybe this is an option for you?

Comment: Yes that too @Chris, there are a thousand ways to skin this cat.

Comment: @AndrewA. I looked into it and the AWS WorkMail service might not be addressing the "work email" aspect, but more so its own workmail emails.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways. One possibility is as shown here:

[image]

That is described here: https://towardsdatascience.com/extract-email-attachment-using-aws-624614a2429b